# GWT, MVP - many widgets, best practice

Tags: java, gwt, dto

I'm building my first GWT app, designed in MVP pattern. Now I've got a view which should populate a DTO which has many fields (aprox. 20). I want it make it clean here what would be the cleanest/less painful way to pass all these widgets/values to my dto?

Creating for each DTO field a widget and passing the value by a onClickHandler? This would be a lot of boilercode, there must be another way. There is a FormPanel but while reading the GWT mailing list it should be used only on file uploads.

Just for sake of completeness: I'm using GWTP for my project which simplifies the basic MVP stuff.

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for (like you question still is not that weired :) ) if you are after UI bind use UI binder if You are after Disptach(back end) binding have a look at GWT Platform framework much more mature than GWTs own MVP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a databinding solution than you should take a look at [GWT's ui editors](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiEditors.html).

From the GWT Docs:

> The GWT Editor framework allows data stored in an object graph to be
>   mapped onto a graph of Editors. The typical scenario is wiring objects
>   returned from an RPC mechanism into a UI.

The editor framework uses a combination of deferred-binding and naming convention to reduce boiler plate code. The system is highly-customizable so you can use annotations to specify editor for bean properties, if for some reason you cannot follow the naming convention.

Comment: Thats it, such a thing I was looking for. Thanks Tahir

Answer (score 2):

I use [UiBinder](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html) for almost all of my widgets. It encourages proper separation of presentation and logic and helps keep to keep track of your widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Your View interface should contain at least one method for every property you want to display/edit. So for example if your DTO has a property "name" then your View interface should contain a method for this property.

```
interface ExampleView extends View {

    // for a textbox
    HasValue<String> getName();

    // for a label
    HasText getName();

    // maybe a save button, for updating the dto and further actions
    HasClickHandlers getSaveButton();
}
```

Now your presenter can set data from the DTO to your view or in case of a textbox, you're able to read the changed value from the widgets.

Updating the DTO back from the widgets could be realized using [ValueChangeHandler](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/logical/shared/ValueChangeHandler.html), which is bound to the HasValue interface, or your ViewImpl could have a Button which notifys your presenter to update the DTO.

This solution leads to more code (boilerplate), but separates the model from the view.

Here the API docs for the various interfaces [HasValue](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HasValue.html), [HasText](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HasText.html) and [HasClickHandlers](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/HasClickHandlers.html) .

Comment: I know how to achieve this my question points to the "problem": If I have so many fields in my DTO my view interface should hold all of these widgets. That seems messy to me.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the different ways to achieve the solution and then ask the following.

- Has the least lines of code.
- Has the least cylomatic complexity. Something with few if any ifs and mostly basic getters is a lot better than something requiring one method that has a lot of conditional code.
- Which is the simplest to read. Lots of small building blocks is better than one big one.
- Which is easiest to test in isolation.

The best solution is the one you find easiest to read, change and test.